# Proving some property of a set of logical expressions that satisfies some properties

Tags: logic, compactness

I am stuck at this problem.

---

Let $\Sigma$ be a (finite/ infinite) set of logical expression (I.e. strings of the form $(P\land Q)$ or $\lnot(P\lor \lnot (Q\land R))$ etc.).

That satisfies the following two properties:

(1) for all $\alpha,\beta\in\Sigma$, $\alpha \Rightarrow \beta$ or $\beta \Rightarrow\alpha$.

(2) for each $\alpha\in \Sigma$ there exists a model $M$ such that $M \vDash \alpha$.

(The symbol $\Rightarrow$ denotes Logical consequence (or implication), That is, if $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are logical expressions such that $\alpha \Rightarrow \beta$, then it must be the case that for each row in the truth table where $\alpha$ is $T$, $\beta$ must also be $T$. And if $\alpha \nRightarrow \beta$, then it must be the case that there exist a row in the truth table where $\alpha$ is $T$ and $\beta$ is $F$).

Prove that there exists a model $M$ such that for all $\alpha\in\Sigma$ we have $M\vDash\alpha$.

---

I tried to prove it by contradiction but I got stuck since the set $\Sigma$ can be uncountable.
Maybe the compactness theorem can help.

**Here's what I've done so far:**

Suppose by contradiction that:

(*) for each model $M$ there exists $\alpha\in\Sigma$ such that $M\nvDash\alpha$

Now we will try to show that there exists a model $M$ such that for all $\alpha\in\Sigma$ we have $M\vDash\alpha$ and so we will get a contradiction

if $\Sigma\neq\emptyset$ is a finite set (similiar proof if $\Sigma$ is countable).

Let $\alpha\in\Sigma$ we get by (2) that there exists a model $M_1$ such that $M_1\vDash \alpha$

Now by (*) we get that there exists $\beta\in\Sigma$ such that $M_1\nvDash \beta$.

Now we will show that $\alpha\nRightarrow\beta$

if $\alpha\Rightarrow\beta$ then we will get that for each model $M$ such that $M\vDash\alpha$ we get $M\vDash\beta$, and so in particular we will get that for the model $M_1$ we have that $M_1\vDash\beta$ since $M_1\vDash\alpha$ which contradicts the fact that $M_1\nvDash\beta$
and so we must get that $\alpha\nRightarrow\beta$.

Now by (1) we get that it must be the case that $\beta\Rightarrow\alpha$
and so we get that for each model $M$, if $M\vDash\beta$ then $M\vDash\alpha$.

No since $\beta\in\Sigma$ we get by (2) that there exists a model $M_2$ such that $M_2\vDash\beta$ and so we get from the fact $\beta\Rightarrow\alpha$, that it must be the case that $M_2\vDash\alpha$.

By contiueing in this process we can add more and more elements from the set $\Sigma$ such that we will get at the end that we have found a model $M$ that satisfies the property:

for all $\sigma\in\Sigma$ we have $M\vDash\sigma$

which contradicts the supposition (*).

And so we must have that:

there exists a model $M$ such that for all $\alpha\in\Sigma$ we have $M\vDash\alpha$.

As was to be shown.

Q.E.D.

---

Thanks for any hint/help.

Comment: Why is unaccountability a problem? I might be missing something but what stops you from just a straightforward application of the compactness theorem once you have shown that (1) implies that every finite subset has a model? That should follow with a little bit of graph theory unless I'm mistaken. (consider whether there could be a complete oriented graph such that after collapsing cycles no vertex would be an origin.)

Comment: @DRF I've written my "proof", much thanks if you can look at it.

Comment: There are two slight issues with your proof. The first is that at some point you say "By continuing in this process we can add more and more elements from the set Σ". That's not very rigorous you should probably do an induction here, but thankfully that should be easy. 

The second problem is much bigger. You completely ignore the problem that you pointed out at the beginning which is that $\Sigma$ might not be finite. If you have even a countably infinite $\Sigma$ then even a proper induction won't cover it. Luckily this is where you invoke the compactness theorem.

Comment: Can you help me a little with how to invoke it exactly. First we must show that for every finite subset  $K$ of $\Sigma$ we get that the exists a model $M$ such that $M\vDash K$ by induction on the number elements in the set $K$. And then we can get by the compactness theorem that there exist a model $M$ such that $M\vDash\Sigma$. Is this supposed to be the flow of the proof?

Comment: You got it exactly. Just formulate the induction correctly. You don't really want your inductive hypothesis to be that a set of $n$ expressions has a model. That would be hard to prove. Instead use that for every set $K$ of $n$ expressions there is an $\alpha\in K$ such that $\forall \beta\in K (\alpha\implies\beta)$.

Comment: I tried to prove that for every set $K$ of $n$ expressions there is an $\alpha\in K$ such that $\forall \beta\in K(\alpha\Rightarrow\beta)$. but I do not get what exactly I need to do in the inductive step. How can I be sure that the $\alpha$'s guaranteed by the induction hypothesys are the same $\alpha$'s ? Thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22769/discussion-between-drf-and-saita).